# Difference between ts parameter definitions - myFunc({data}: {data: ExampleType}) {} vs myFunc(data:ExampleType) {}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, destructuring

I'm working on a TypeScript project and came across two different parameter definitions in some code. Both seem to achieve the same result, but I'm not sure if there's any significant difference between them. Could someone please explain the difference between the following two parameter definitions?

```
export default function myFunc(data: MyDataType) {}
```

vs

```
export default function myFunc({ data }: { data: MyDataType }) {}
```

Both definitions seem to accept an object of type MyDataType as a parameter. Are there any advantages or specific use cases for using one over the other? Any insights would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Call site is different: the former should be called as `myFunc(new MyDataType())` and the latter - as `myFunc({data: new MyDataType()})`

Comment: `MyDataType` is not necessarily a `class`, maybe a TypeScript `type` or `interface`

Answer (score 2):

The two definitions are not identical, the first one takes one parameter named `data` of type `MyDataType` and the second takes an object with one property named `data`, of type `MyDataType`.

The second signature makes use of destructuring which extracts `data` for use in the function body, so in both cases you have one `data` variable of type `MyDataType` available in the function scope.

The only difference is the structure of the input parameter.

Comment: I didn't quite understand a clear distinction about when and in what situations these two parameter definitions create differences. Lets say 
export interface Worksheet {
    content: string,
    questions: [string],
    answers: [string],
    title: string
}
Whats the differance between using 
export default function GeneratePDF({data}: {data: Worksheet}) {}
vs
export default function GeneratePDF(data:Worksheet) {}

Comment: Well do you want a single object with multiple properties? Or multiple parameters? The choice is yours it just depends on the case. Note that TypeScript duck typing would allow you to pass any object that has at least the required property. The others would simply be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Both are different here based on the type of parameters:

```
export default function myFunc(data: MyDataType) {}
```

accept parameter `data` with type `MyDataType`

```
export default function myFunc({ data }: { data: MyDataType }) {}
```

accept parameter object with the `data` propety as `MyDataType` type

If we suppose to enhance and add more parameters then recommended would be second one so we can destructure as much as we can:

```
export default function myFunc({ data, data2, data3 }: { data: MyDataType, data1: MyDataType1, data2: MyDataType2 }) {}
```

Hope it will help you to decide.